# Relationship between X and Y if both are uniformly distributed over the same range

Tags: probability, random-variables

For independent X and Y, each uniformly distributed on (1,2,...,n) how would I go about calculating $P(X=Y)$ and $P(X<Y)$? Do I draw an n by n matrix and visually analyze it?

The solution talks about using symmetry, but I am not sure how to approach this. What is the relationship between X and Y given they are distributed over the same range?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Since they are independent, you have, for every $1\leq i,j\leq n$,
$$
\Pr[ X=i, Y=j ] = \Pr[ X=i ]\Pr[ Y=j ] = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n^2}\,,
$$
where we used the fact that they are both uniformly distributed.

Now, by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) the probability that $X=Y$ is equal to:
$$
\Pr[ X = Y ] = \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr[ X = i, Y =i ] = n\cdot \frac{1}{n^2} = \boxed{\frac{1}{n}}\,.
$$

Note that this generalizes to other distributions than uniform. If $X,Y$ are independent with common distribution $p$ over $\{1,\dots,n\}$, then the same argument gives
$$
\Pr[ X = Y ] = \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr[ X = i, Y =i ] = \sum_{i=1}^n p(i)^2 = \lVert p\rVert_2^2\,,
$$
which is the squared $\ell_2$ norm of the probability distribution $p$ (minimized for the uniform distribution) and is commonly referred to as the *collision probability.*

---

For the probability that $X<Y$, you can use the same approach (law of total probability):
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X<Y] &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr[X=i, Y>i]
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr[X=i]\cdot\Pr[Y>i]
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-i}{n}
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-i}{n}
= 1- \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i
= 1-\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}
= 
\boxed{\frac{n-1}{2n}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: As a sanity check: when $n=1$, $\Pr[X<Y]=0$. When $n\to\infty$, $\Pr[X<Y]\to \frac{1}{2}$. And when $n=2$, you find  $\Pr[X<Y]=\frac{1}{4}$ as expected (since the 4 events $(1,1),(2,2), (1,2)$, and $(2,1)$ are equiprobable, but $X<Y$ in only one of them).

Comment: Did not study 'common distribution', so I do not really know the difference between uniform and common. Also we did not study the Law of total probability, so I am just trying to understand what P(X=Y) means in terms of X and Y? I think it is the sum of probabilities of all the pairs like (1,1), (2,2) etc. But how do I go from having n such pairs to the answer which is $1/n$ especially since I do not know what the probability of any such pair is?

Comment: By "common" I meant "common to $X$ and $Y$" (as in the usual English use of the word, not any mathematical one). @EvaD

Comment: As for the second question: The event $\{X=Y\}$ corresponds to the disjoint union of the $n$ events $\{X=Y=i\}$, for $1\leq i\leq n$: $$\{X=Y\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{X=Y=i\}$$ Since these events are disjoint, you have by the axioms of probability that $$\Pr[X=Y] = \Pr[\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{X=Y=i\}] = \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr[ \{X=Y=i\} ]$$ (which is basically the law of total probability: fancy name, but simple notion). Now, by independence $\Pr[ \{X=Y=i\} ] = \Pr[ \{X=i\} ]\Pr[ \{Y=i\} ] $ and since $X,Y$ are uniform you get $1/n^2$. So $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$. @EvaD

Comment: @EvaD So to answer you last point *"especially since I do not know what the probability of any such pair is"*: well, you **do**. By independence of $X,Y$ and the fact that $X,Y$ are both uniformly distribution, each pair has probability $\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @EvaD Let me know if something is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

(You asked how symmetry is used.)

Yes, consider the $n\times n$ table of $p_{x,y}=P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)= n^{-2}.$ This table has the same entry everywhere, so $P(X=Y)$ is just $n^{-2}$ times the number of elements  $(n)$ on the diagonal where $x=y$, while $P(X<Y)$ is just $n^{-2}$ times the number of elements ($\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$) in the triangular off-diagonal part where $x<y$.